# "Escolher linguagem com base em especificações" fechada como opinativa

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, escopo-do-site

Me parece que a pergunta *[Como pegar informações de outro programa em execução?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31782/201)* tem umas necessidades bem claras e admitiria somente respostas do tipo:

- Sim/Não é possível com Java por isto e por aquilo
- Sim/Não é possível com C++ [...]
- Sim/Não é possível com C [...]

Seria útil se o autor da pergunta acrescentasse detalhes sobre a pesquisa que fez, mas acho bem respondível no estado atual. Opiniões?

Comment: Votei pra reabrir. Quase certeza que no final das contas vai ter que apelar pra C++, mas dou uma recompensa pra quem conseguir uma API pra isso em Java ou .NET.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## O problema com a pergunta

O "problema" é que sempre que alguém pergunta *qual linguagem* ou *qual framework* ou *qual biblioteca* há várias respostas e geralmente são opinativas porque é possível alcançar aquele resultado de várias formas.

No caso específico da questão citada, há alguns problemas, por exemplo:

- Não há informação de qual o sistema operacional utilizado.
- Não é claro se o requisito é verificar somente a janela do emulador ZSNES ou se seria algo genérico para qualquer aplicativo (o que torna a pergunta muito ampla).
- O título da pergunta não está correto, porque não é a linguagem que dá acesso a um processo sendo executado e sim a API do sistema operacional, como o Tony bem informou, embora nesse caso não seja *culpa* do OP, apenas desconhecimento.

Tudo isso fora a falta de humildade do OP.

## SOpt vs. SO

Não é infrequente novos usuários que são negativados ou têm suas perguntas fechadas compararem o SOpt com o SO dizendo que "estamos ficando como eles" ou coisa pior.

Primeiro, é importante ter humildade para enxergar as coisas do ponto de vista dos outros.

Segundo, o "pt" do "SOpt" não o torna a "casa da mãe Joana" onde devemos passar a mão na cabeça de todos.

Aqui nós também buscamos qualidade e excelência de conteúdo. Não somos os primos vira-latas. Mas é claro que isso não significa que queremos ser iguais.

Estamos abertos a novos usuários e percebo que muitos dos usuários atuais, além de nós moderadores, estão se esforçando para **instruir** os novos usuários a manter um padrão mínimo de qualidade.

Os usuários que se esforçam um pouco e adequam-se às regras logo são saudados com votos positivos e agradecimentos. Somente os que não sabem ouvir críticas é que acabam se afastando logo. Digo isso como quem acompanhou o SOpt desde o seu primeiro dia, sem ter nenhuma experiência com o SO anteriormente.

## Salvando a pergunta

Bem, voltando à pergunta, ela pode ser facilmente "salva" se o título for mudado para algo do tipo *Como inspecionar informações de um programa em execução no Windows?*.

E então o conteúdo da pergunta deveria especificar claramente se a ideia é apenas para o ZSNES ou não. Isso porque há informações que a API do sistema operacional permite obter, geralmente estão ligadas a interface, mas somente se o programa usar componentes padrão do Sistema Operacional, que com certeza não é o caso desse emulador.

Já variáveis e estruturas de dados internas exigiriam uma engenharia reversa da memória, o que é até possível, mas muito complicado. Duvido que algum usuário iria se dar ao trabalho de fazer isso para responder em detalhes. Entretanto, seria possível responder pelo menos com um direcionamento e dizendo se é possível ou não.

Comment: Recentemente fizeram [uma pergunta parecida](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28377/como-ler-vari%C3%A1vel-de-outro-programa), mas que pedia justamente isso que você fala no final (ler valores de variáveis de outro processo). Quando vi a pergunta do Gabriel ontem, na hora lembrei da outra (que foi difícil de achar!). A dele me parece pedir algo factível. Pode ser melhorada, claro, mas não acho que devesse estar fechada.

Comment: Realmente @bfavaretto, concordo que não precisava ter sido fechada, apenas reformulada.

Comment: Ambas as perguntas muito interessantes, concordo com os dois.